# Update mysql table record

Tags: php, mysql

I just curious about updating mysql table record (in connection with php) as follows.

1. Update a value. Eg: In mysql table it has value "100". User wants add "50" to that value. Using php code pass "50" to mysql table and it adds "50" to "100" and update to "150".
2. Append data to a existing value.
   Eg: There is already a number in mysql table field "Contact" (0123456789)and new number should be append to the same field and separate using a comma or something (0123456789, 9876543210). Not using fields contact1, contact2 etc.

I am asking this normally we retrieve all the data from the table and do all the mathematical operations and after all we overwrite and update the table. Is there a way in the dbms to manage this kind of situation?

Comment: Before,you get,down voted, you may want to update your question with your sample table schema, sample expected output and any relevant code you may have tried :-)

Comment: @BonCodigo Why should that be relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 1 you could use

```
set col =col + 50
```

and for two you could use

```
set contact = case when contact is null then '12345' else concat(contact, ',  12345') end
```

but using csv in a database is only a good thing in certain situstions. This is not one of them I think. I would use a one to many relation with a seperate table. Consider the following.

1. removing one contact number means parsing the string and creating a new value.
2. find people with a certain number
3. ordering by number

Comment: Actually I want to only store a values in contact field. And actual use is to save some serial numbers. They do not want to be searched, sorted or deleted. Just save and display. Thanks.

Comment: Then I hope nobody ever askes you to export a list of all used serial numbers. In my expierence people never know what they need in the (near) future. I always play on the safe side when it comes to things like this.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question you raised:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column_with_ints = column_with_ints + 50;
```

For the second answer, you can concatenate strings in MySQL the same way.

```
UPDATE tablename SET column_with_string = CONCATE(column_with_stringA, column_with_stringB);
```

Answer (score 1):

When update you can reference to the current field value.

e.g.

query for 1.

```
UPDATE table SET col1 = col1+50 WHERE condition;
```

query for 2.

```
UPDATE table SET col1 = CONCAT( col1, ', 9876543210' );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Update myTable set MyValue=MyValue+50 where myId=x
2. Update myTable set MyValue=CONCAT(MyValue,',9876543210') where myId=x